# How to properly stop bash script?

Tags: supervisord, ubuntu-server

I have this in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myscript.conf

```
[program:my_script]
directory=/var/www/myfolder
command=/var/www/myscript.sh
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stopsignal=KILL
```

This is content of myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -n /var/www/binaryfolder/binaryfile /var/www/myfolder
/var/www/myfolder/binaryfile
```

This is working but when I stop supervisor this binaryfile keeps running.

I know there will be questions like why don't you copy that file manually and then execute by supervisor, but that is not possible because that file is dynamically passed to myscript.sh.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since starting `binaryfile` is the last command, you can easily solve the problem by modifying myscript.sh as

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -n /var/www/binaryfolder/binaryfile /var/www/myfolder
exec /var/www/myfolder/binaryfile
```

Please note that `exec` is added at the beginning of the last line which replaces the shell process with binaryfile process so supervisord stops that process. For more information you can check

http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html

If you totally want solve this from supervisord configuration and your supervisord version is greater or equal to 3.0b1, you can add `stopasgroup=true` parameter.

So your new config file should be

```
[program:my_script]
directory=/var/www/myfolder
command=/var/www/myscript.sh
numprocs=1
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stopsignal=KILL
stopasgroup=true
```

For more information about supervisord configuration, please check: 
http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings